# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process [NOT A DUPLICATE]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

(My firefox version is Mozilla Firefox version 63.0 so it's not the same problem as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with))

I get the following error when following the https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_01.html book .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/python-tdd-book/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/python-tdd-book/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/python-tdd-book/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/python-tdd-book/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/python-tdd-book/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

when running "python functional_tests.py".

which contains the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

assert "Django" in browser.title
```

I would also like to note that I'm running Ubuntu Bash on Windows 10.

Selenium-3.141.0

geckodriver 0.23.0

Python 3.6.6