# Selenium exception: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to run a firefox browser with geckodriver in ubuntu and get the error:  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

I've looked at this [WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process with GeckoDriver, Selenium and Python on RaspberryPi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with)

and checked the versions that I'm using and think they should all be compatible.
Firefox version 66.03
Geckodriver 0.24.0
Python 3.6.7

I've also confirmed that the geckodriver is in the path, but still getting no joy.

Many thanks for any help.

```
  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```