# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to do some web scraping using python and selenium and I am struggling from the first lines of code. I am using Ubuntu 19.

The error I get:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

Here is my code:

```
full_name=list()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

full_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="case-title"]/h3')

num_page_items = len(full_name)
for i in range(num_page_items):
    print(full_name[i].text)
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535654/7727955) answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process with GeckoDriver, Selenium and Python on RaspberryPi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with)