# RSelenium rsDriver gives error can't kill an exited process

Tags: r, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, rselenium

I am struggling to make RSelenium work on a unix server. It has Mozilla Firefox 60.6.1, and running the two commands:

```
binman::list_versions("geckodriver")
$linux64
[1] "0.22.0" "0.23.0" "0.24.0"

binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")
$generic
[1] "3.141.59"      "4.0.0-alpha-1" "4.0.0-alpha-2"
```

it seems that the geckodriver is available (is it ?). But when I try to launch a driver :

```
> library(RSelenium)
> rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
+          extraCapabilities = list(
+            "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
+              binary = "/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox",
+              args = list('--headless')
+            )
+          ))
...
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'login2.cluster', ip: '192.168.100.12', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace:

Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
         Summary: UnknownError
         Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
         Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with) and others I tried to downgrade the version of geckodriver, and make use of the headless mode of firefox:

```
 rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
                version = "3.141.59",
                geckover = "0.22.0",
          extraCapabilities = list(
            "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
              binary = "/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox",
              args = list('--headless')
            )
          ))
```

But still get the same error.
My suspicion would be that geckodriver is actually not installed. Is this possible ? How to check it ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stick to your exact requirements regarding *Selenium*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox* versions which would be used in your test framework and remove the unwanted versions of binaries totally. *GeckoDriver v0.24.0* being the latest release must be the chosen one.

*Selenium v4.0.0-alpha-1* and *Selenium v4.0.0-alpha-2* are **alpha** releases and must be avoided for **Production** usage. So *Selenium v3.141.59* being the latest release must be the chosen one.

> For *GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility you can find a detailed discussion in [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)

**Note**: You don't need to install the **GeckoDriver** binary but put the binary in the desired location.

So an ideal usage would be:

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
        version = "3.141.59",
        geckover = "0.24.0",
      extraCapabilities = list(
        "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
          binary = "/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox",
          args = list('--headless')
        )
      ))
```

If you are still facing the issue follow the below mentioned steps.

---

This error message...

```
message:invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

...can surface for different reasons. The possible solution can be any/either of the following:

- Ensure that *GeckoDriver v0.24.0* is downloaded and placed within the directory that is already in your path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`
- Ensure that *GeckoDriver* is having executable permission for **non-root** users.
- Ensure that *firefox* (> v57.0) is installed (mandatory) within **`/usr/lib64/firefox/`** directory as per your code block and the version is compatable.
- Ensure that if you are running *Firefox* on a system with **no display** you have to use *headless mode*.
- The correct usage of **headless mode** with *GeckoDriver v0.24.0* is:

  ```
  options.headless = True
  ```
- There is no need for `xvfb-run` anymore if you set `MOZ_HEADLESS=1` as follows:

  ```
  $ export MOZ_HEADLESS=1   # this way you only have to set it once
  ```
- If you have changed your system path, take a *System Reboot*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Always execute your *@Tests* as a **non-root** user.

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process with GeckoDriver, Selenium and Python on RaspberryPi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with/52535654#52535654)

Comment: I installed Firefox 68.0.2 , downloaded geckodriver 0.24.0, but I have Selenium 3.141.0 (Google Colab rejected to install 3.141.59). I use python3.7. The error message is the same. I installed Selenium 3.14.0 also, because of Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings(https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), but does not help.

Comment: @vesszabo I think your usecase differs from this usecase in a lot many ways. Can you post the comment updates in the respective discussions please?

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580603/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-erro?noredirect=1#57580603

Comment: @denis missed the bounty :)

Comment: @DebanjanB I an really sorry I don't know how to give it, I was away from computer since end of last week and I don't habe the ooportunity now

Comment: @denis It's okay, glad to be able to help you. When you offer a bounty on a question, you need to reward the bounty to any of the answers with your own conviction and that needs to be done before the bounty period of 7 day (+ the grace period) expires. To reward a bounty you need to click on the respective blue button beside your chosen answer depicting the bounty amount.