# Selenium Geckodriver Firefox not working in a CRONTAB, work on terminal

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, cron, geckodriver

I have a very simple python code that has stopped working recently only when running in a cron.

basically, this is how it began:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1000, 1000))
display.start()

url = "https://www.exemple.com/admin"
opts= Options()
opts.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

driver.get(url)
```

This raise an error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

The geckodriver logs are :

```
1586945401577   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileYPmycq"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1586945401858   addons.webextension.doh-rollout@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'doh-rollout@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: networkStatus
1586945401873   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1586945401873   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1586945401873   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1586945401873   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

Geckodriver version: 0.26
Firefox version: 76.0b4
Python version: 3.6
Selenium version: 3.14.1

Therefor, I think there is no incompatibility problems.
Gecko is executable for all users, and is located in /usr/bin/.

I checked all information find here [WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process with GeckoDriver, Selenium and Python on RaspberryPi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with)

I also tried to launch firefox alone from terminal, by adding DISPLAY:=10 and that worked.

The script work fine from terminal, but once in the CRONTAB, I have the error above.

Also, I killed all firefox process before running.

Comment: I'm running into the same error.  No solutions?  Maybe Mac security settings won't allow cronjobs to open a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making the path to the webdriver explicit.  I.e. I replaced this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

With this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

And magically the cronjob ran fine.