# Unable to start chrome or Firefox driver using etaoin

Tags: http, clojure

I'm using the etaoin library to test for chrome and firefox. I have both chromedriver and gecko driver installed using brew in macOS. 
But when I try using them in the repl, like so:

```
user> (use 'etaoin.api)
(require '[etaoin.keys :as k])
```

-- EDIT --
for firefox:
When trying

```
(def driver (Firefox))


1. Caused by clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
   throw+: {:response {:value {:error "unknown error", :message "invalid
   argument: can't kill an exited process", :stacktrace ""}}, :path "session",
   :payload {:desiredCapabilities {:loggingPrefs {:browser "ALL"}}}, :method
   :post, :type :etaoin/http-error, :port 47131, :host "127.0.0.1", :status 500,
   :driver {:args ("geckodriver" "--port" 47131), :capabilities {:loggingPrefs
   {:browser "ALL"}}, :process #object[java.lang.UNIXProcess 0x2ec0e260
   "java.lang.UNIXProcess@2ec0e260"], :locator "xpath", :type :firefox, :env
   nil, :port 47131, :host "127.0.0.1", :url "http://127.0.0.1:47131"}}
   {:response
    {:value
     {:error "unknown error",
      :message "invalid argument: can't kill an exited process",
      :stacktrace ""}},
    :path "session",
    :payload {:desiredCapabilities {:loggingPrefs {:browser "ALL"}}},
    :method :post,
    :type :etaoin/http-error,
    :port 47131,
    :host "127.0.0.1",
    :status 500,
    :driver
    {:args ("geckodriver" "--port" 47131),
     :capabilities {:loggingPrefs {:browser "ALL"}},
     :process
     #object[java.lang.UNIXProcess 0x2ec0e260 "java.lang.UNIXProcess@2ec0e260"],
     :locator "xpath",
     :type :firefox,
     :env nil,
     :port 47131,
     :host "127.0.0.1",
     :url "http://127.0.0.1:47131"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the chromedriver cannot find Chrome. Do you have Chrome installed? If not, install it. If you have, maybe it cannot find Chrome. Try to install it in the [expected location](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) (/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome).

Comment: okay yeah. I have chrome canary not chrome. But why isn't geckodriver working, i.e., (def driver (Firefox))?

Comment: That one arises when Firefox cannot be opened. Looks like a version mismatch, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with for help. Probably need to download a  version of Firefox that works with the driver. See that answer for suggestion to what version.