# Elements that are in page_source cannot be found when trying to scrape it using BeautifulSoup or Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl Booking.com site for reviews and hotel details. I managed to get the hotels details but when it comes to crawling reviews something weird happens !

I find the container that covers the reviews, but empty...

I made sure the elements I'm looking for are present by inspecting the page using Chrome DevTools

I even switched from using scrapy_splash to selenium in case the former may miss out any dynamic content, I also tried crawling it using BeautifulSoup and Xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DRIVER_PATH = './chromedriver'
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/tn/carlton-tunis.ar.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaECIAQGYAQG4ARnIAQzYAQHoAQH4ARCIAgGoAgO4Ar351vgFwAIB0gIkNDUyNmFhZGQtODNkMy00Nzg1LWI3MzYtNWE4MzA5Y2RjY2Jk2AIG4AIB;dest_id=-731701;dest_type=city;dist=0;from_beach_non_key_ufi_sr=1;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1595260105;srpvid=1d9f6f249e3001d7;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-reviews")
reviewsContainer = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='review_list_page_container']/ul[@class='review_list']")
```

and as I said I get the error of not finding the specified element

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='review_list_page_container']/ul[@class='review_list']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

any help please ? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem:

I'm using Fedora 32 Distro, Selenium being installed in the environment only is not enough. I had to install it using SuperUser priviliges:

```
sudo pip install -U selenium
```

then I made sure my drivers directory is in PATH, so I made one in Home directory, moved Gecko and Chrome drivers there and added it to PATH:

```
export BROWSER_DRIVERS="~/browser_drivers"
export PATH=$PATH:$BROWSER_DRIVERS
```

all working good now: headful, headless whatever...thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple.

The reviews tab is hidden and appears only when the page is load (I'm not good in web and I don't know how they call this technology).

So, when you have the option `--headless` which runs the browser in hidden mode (without loading the UI elements), that hidden tab will not be loaded; the page should be loaded to create it.

The solution is only to disable the `headless` option. I changed your code to use Firefox browser (sorry I don't have Chrome driver :D ):

```
import os, platform
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/tn/carlton-tunis.ar.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaECIAQGYAQG4ARnIAQzYAQHoAQH4ARCIAgGoAgO4Ar351vgFwAIB0gIkNDUyNmFhZGQtODNkMy00Nzg1LWI3MzYtNWE4MzA5Y2RjY2Jk2AIG4AIB;dest_id=-731701;dest_type=city;dist=0;from_beach_non_key_ufi_sr=1;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1595260105;srpvid=1d9f6f249e3001d7;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-reviews")
reviewsContainer = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='review_list_page_container']/ul[@class='review_list']")
```

if you change `options.headless` to `True`, you will have the error.

Comment: this is the new error I get when I use your code as it is !

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Comment: @RakiLachraf .. you have active instances hidden. Try to kill them using the task manager. If you're not able to find them, restart you PC.

Comment: I have Fedora distro,  and I killed all Firefox processes using "killall firefox"... still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you try to restart it? or to try the code on another machine?

Comment: BTW, someone mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with , that you need to have specific versions for firefox and the driver, not a random combination.

Comment: yep, saw that and I made sure they are compatible...