# Sidekiq job getting Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process (but only when run async)

Tags: selenium, heroku, capybara, sidekiq, geckodriver

I have a Sidekiq job that uses Capybara, deployed on a Heroku dyno. I run into the following issue even with Sidekiq concurrency=1.

When run asynchronously, the jobs sometimes return the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

But never ever synchronously on Heroku

When I look at the Selenium debug logs, I see:

```
[Parent 993, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: Failed to launch tab subprocess: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/glue/GeckoChildProcessHost.cpp, line 647
[Parent 993, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (34): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 353
JavaScript error: chrome://global/content/bindings/remote-browser.xml, line 240: TypeError: this.frameLoader.tabParent is null
JavaScript error: chrome://global/content/bindings/remote-browser.xml, line 366: NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIScriptSecurityManager.getLoadContextCodebasePrincipal]
(firefox:993): GConf-WARNING **: 18:44:30.591: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

[This thread](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4051) gives a fix for a similar but ultimately different issue also involving `$DISPLAY`. However, I ssh'ed in and set $DISPLAY to `[:0.0]` to no avail.

#### Further Notes:

- In [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534658/webdriverexception-message-invalid-argument-cant-kill-an-exited-process-with), someone suggested a version mismatch between Geckodriver and Firefox could cause `can't kill an exited process`. However, my versions are compatible, using latest Selenium, Firefox, and geckodriver. And yes, I'm running headless=true.
- If relevant to the above, I also periodically get the following issues (also only while async, I can remove this if not relevant):

`ThreadError: can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable`

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4457`

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeoutError: Connection refused (os error 111)`

`Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)`