# How to create a lambda layer with selenium 3 and firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, aws-lambda-layers

I have a working docker container and want migrate to a lambda layer for selenium 3.141 on firefox. Dockerfile for the working container is:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install selenium==3.141.0

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install wget bzip2 firefox-esr #68.12.0esr
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz

RUN tar -zxf geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin/
```

When I execute the following in this container a `Firefox` object is created.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options   import Options
opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
Firefox(options=opts, service_log_path='/home/geckodriver.log')
```

For the lambda layer I use an `amazonlinux` image for local testing. On aws a zip file I provide will be extracted into `/opt`, so I want to put everything into `/opt` and see if it works.

My dockerfile for that is

```
FROM amazonlinux

WORKDIR /
RUN yum update -y

# Install Python 3.7
RUN yum install python3 zip unzip wget tar bzip2 bzip2-libs gzip -y

RUN pip3.7 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3.7 install selenium==3.141.0 #-t /opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages
  
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxf geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz -C /opt

RUN wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/68.9.0esr/linux-x86_64/de/firefox-68.9.0esr.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xvjf firefox-68.9.0esr.tar.bz2 -C /opt
```

But when I run that with

```
sudo docker build -t selenium:fftest -f Dockerfile.ff .
sudo docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data selenium:fftest
```

and execute

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options   import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
firefox_dir = '/opt/'
gecko_dir = '/opt/'
binary = FirefoxBinary( firefox_dir + 'firefox/firefox')
Firefox(options=opts, executable_path= gecko_dir + 'geckodriver', firefox_binary=binary)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

## I've tried

### checking version compatibility

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535654/3014199 suggests version incompatibilities but according to the [table](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html) I'm fine with selenium 3.141, Geckodriver 22 and Firefox 68.

### running it as a non-root user

The linked answer further suggests running as a non root user. I've finally managed to do that with:

```
FROM amazonlinux

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install python3 wget tar bzip2 bzip2-libs gzip -y
Run yum install shadow-utils -y
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash jd
RUN echo "jd:password" | chpasswd
RUN usermod -aG root jd
USER jd
WORKDIR /home/jd

RUN pip3.7 install --user --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.7 install --user selenium==3.141.0
  
COPY downloads/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz /tmp/
COPY downloads/firefox-68.9.0esr.tar.bz2 /tmp/

USER root

RUN tar -zxf /tmp/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz -C /opt
RUN tar -xvjf /tmp/firefox-68.9.0esr.tar.bz2 -C /opt
RUN chown -R jd:jd /opt/firefox
USER jd
```

Everything in `/opt` has `jd` as owner and group, but the error message is the same.

### extracting everything into /usr/local/bin

When I extract both geckodriver and firefox into `/usr/local/bin` I cann instantiate with just `Firefox(options=opts)` but get the same `can't kill an exited process` error.

### inspecting the binaries

```
$ /opt/firefox/firefox --version
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I think the missing object file is the root cause. But I don't know where to get it and where to put it(I can only put it in `/opt`).

After `yum install gtk3-devel` `libdbus-glib-1.so.2` is missing for file `/opt/firefox/libxul.so`.

Comment: Any luck? 

I've tried downloading [this firefox binary](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/39.0b7/linux-x86_64/en-US/) to a mounted EFS partition, but I get an error that the binary is not a binary when calling it as headless with the correct geckodriver version.

Comment: Ive got the same `can't kill an exited process` error, but `firefox --version` doesn't show any errors.
At first I forgot to set the lambda's memory limit, and it was capped at 128. I've raised that but I'm still getting the same error.
I'm using FFox 84 & geko driver v0.27.0 and I've based my docker image on  public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

Comment: @peer did you ever found a solution?

Comment: @DavidMauricio I ended up switching from Firefox to Chome